# How do you determine if two triangles are intersecting for collision detection?

Tags: algorithms, triangles, 3d, collision-detection

I've been scouring the internet for things about intersecting triangles. I haven't been able to find something that just gives me the math and what all the variables are equal to. I would love the math and explanation and values of each variable if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Look for papers by Thomas Akenine-Moller (or just Moller; umlaut over the o). He's written more efficient triangle-triangle intersection code that most people can dream about.